# Как при наведении плавно выровнять текст по центру

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно чтобы весь текст был по центру и плавно это происходило, а не скачком и возвращался чтобы тоже плавно

```css
.title {
  transition: 1s;
}

.title:hover {
  text-align: center;
  transition: 1s;
}

.title:hover~.block{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="title">Текст</h1>
  <div class="block">
    <p class="text">длииииииииииииинный текст </p>
    <p class="text"> короткий текст </p>
    <p class="text"> обычный текст </p>
    <p class="text"> снова длииииииииинный текст </p>
    <p class="text"> короткий текст</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @LevShportak transition не подходит под text-align

Comment: Является ли разделение текста на элементы с блочным представлением (в данном случае параграфы) условием задачи?.. или надо чтобы с `<br>`'ами и `white-space: pre[-line];` тоже работало?

Comment: Да, являются условием задачи именно и только P

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно заанимировать width.

```css
.title,
.block {
  transition: width 1s;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.title:hover {
  text-align: center;
  transition: 1s;
  width: 100%;
}

.title:hover~.block{
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="title">Текст</h1>
  <div class="block">
    <p class="text">длииииииииииииинный текст </p>
    <p class="text"> короткий текст </p>
    <p class="text"> обычный текст </p>
    <p class="text"> снова длииииииииинный текст </p>
    <p class="text"> короткий текст</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: у вас почему-то переход в обратное состояние без анимации

Comment: Вариант хороший, но есть проблемы. Если заголовок сильно больше текста, то он сразу ждет пока текст преодолеет определенную ширину, а потом только начинает двигаться. Так же если поставить не 1s, а 3 и больше, то после наведения нужно ждать эти 3 секунды, чтобы навести еще раз, ибо он не успеет вернуться в исходное положение и начнет с того момента где остановился, а так как плавной анимации назад нет, то выглядит плохо

Answer (score 1):

Если исходить из вопроса:

> Как при наведении плавно выровнять текст по центру

и условий:

> Нужно чтобы весь текст был по центру и плавно это происходило, а не скачком и возвращался чтобы тоже плавно

то задача решается просто:

```css
.title, .text {
  width: min-content;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: 3s ease;
}

div:not(.block):hover .title, div:not(.block):hover .text {
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translatex(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="title">Текст длииииииииииииинный</h1>
  <div class="block">
    <p class="text">длииииииииииииинный текст</p>
    <p class="text">короткий текст</p>
    <p class="text">самый обычный текст</p>
    <p class="text">снова длииииииииинный текст</p>
    <p class="text">короткий текст</p>
  </div>
</div>
```